# Centos server rebooted unexpectedly and i'm unable to process crash file, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: linux, centos6, dump

One of my Mysql replication servers has rebooted during the night and i'm trying to find the reason.
Running the command `last` shows this line:
`reboot   system boot  2.6.32-71.29.1.e Wed Jul 31 04:37 - 11:02  (06:24)`
I'm trying to read the `vmcore` file which has been created during the reboot.
I've installed `kernel-debuginfo` package which created the `vmlinux` file.
then I ran:

```
[root@dbs ~]# crash -s /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64/vmlinux /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2013-07-31-01:33:32/vmcore
crash 6.1.0-1.el6
crash: invalid kernel virtual address: 68f8e06b73fe5f1f  type: "possible"
WARNING: cannot read cpu_possible_map
crash: invalid kernel virtual address: fce96c6b73fe5f1f  type: "present"
WARNING: cannot read cpu_present_map
crash: invalid kernel virtual address: e10de07591befc69  type: "online"
WARNING: cannot read cpu_online_map
crash: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2 and /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2013-07-31-01:33:32/vmcore do not match!

Usage:

  crash [OPTION]... NAMELIST MEMORY-IMAGE  (dumpfile form)
  crash [OPTION]... [NAMELIST]             (live system form)

Enter "crash -h" for details.
[root@dbs ~]#
```

Can anyone please point me to what I'm doing wrong?
I wonder how come vmcore and vmlinux do not much as the vmlinux was generated when I installed the kernel-debuginfo package...

```
[root@dbs 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64]# rpm -qa |grep kernel-debug
kernel-debuginfo-common-x86_64-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
kernel-debug-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-debuginfo-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
[root@dbs 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64]# uname -r
2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64
[root@dbs 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64]#
```

Why did the `kernel-debuginfo` package generated the wrong `vmlinux`?
`uname -r` shows kernel version 2.6.32-71.29.1 while the `vmlinux` which has been generated is of version 2.6.32-358.14.1 ?

```
[root@dbs ~]# yum list installed |grep kernel
abrt-addon-kerneloops.x86_64
dracut-kernel.noarch    004-33.2.el6_0  @updates                                
kernel.x86_64           2.6.32-71.el6   @anaconda-CentOS-201106060106.x86_64/6.0
kernel.x86_64           2.6.32-71.29.1.el6
kernel-debuginfo.x86_64 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.centos.plus
kernel-debuginfo-common-x86_64.x86_64
kernel-headers.x86_64   2.6.32-71.29.1.el6
[root@dbs ~]#
```

Comment: 2.6.32-71.29.1.e is that some custom complied kernel?

Comment: As far as I know, not.

Comment: I've added some more information to the question

Comment: # yum list installed | grep kernel ?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
The steps I did:

```
[root@dbs ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64
[root@dbs ~]#
```

I ran:

```
[root@dbs ~]# yum provides kernel-debuginfo-2.6.32
```

And manually looked for:

```
kernel-debuginfo-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64
```

I then ran: 
`rpm -qa |grep ^kernel` and `yum remove`'ed the current installed wrong version of `kernel-debuginfo`.

Then I installed the correct `kernel-debuginfo-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64`, ran `updatedb` and then `locate`'d the new `vmlinux` with the correct version. Then I used the next command: `crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64/vmlinux /var/crash/127.0.0.1-2013-07-31-01\:33\:32/vmcore` and the crash report ran successfully.
Thanks for your help @ALex_hha .

Comment: I am having same issue. I checked the kernel version and the debug info kernel package version are same, however, I am still getting the error 

crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffffffff80488620  type: "present"
WARNING: cannot read cpu_present_map
crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffffffff804832e0  type: "online"
WARNING: cannot read cpu_online_map
crash: page excluded: kernel virtual address: ffffffff8048a240  type: "xtime"

Comment: Does the running kernel need to be the debug kernel? If I run the debug kernel and then panic it, I am able to get it work with the dump, however, if I run the normal kernel and then panic it to get the dump it does not work

Comment: I used it on a regular kernel, not a debug one